# MACRO and populating cells on one sheet based on two randomized pieces of info on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am in hotel housekeeping management. I need a better way to track the progress of rooms being cleaned everyday.

I created a visual depiction of the hotel in excel spreadsheet, where if a room (a cell in my spreadsheet) has a "3" in it, the cell turns red and another graph at the bottom will count the room. That way if I have 35 rooms which need to be cleaned by 3pm i can see where they are located across the hotel, and have a specific count of them displayed at the bottom of the page. The same goes for 2pm checkins with the number "2"except it turns blue.

Now for the tricky part...I need the entire chart to automatically populate so that each cells value is determined by two different pieces of information on a different spreadsheet and from 2 different columns on that spreadsheet. The information in column 1 is random and needs to be found, but the information in column 2 is located directly across, and is directly related to, its counterpart in column 1.

I need 1] the room number located in the column 1 on the other spreadsheet to automatically correspond to the correct cell (or room number) on my spreadsheet. 2] In column 2 on the other spreadsheet it lists the times they check in (14:00pm, 15:00pm). I need the time in column 2 to correspond with the room number in column 1 as it populates my chart automatically.

So if room 305 is in the list (not all rooms will be), and in the column next to it shows a 14:00 (2pm) arrival, I need the correct cell in my spreadsheet (room 305) to populate with the number 2. If it was room 305 with a 3pm arrival, it would need to automatically populate with a number 3. I know MACRO will have to be used, but I cant figure out the formulas to change my cell based on the room number which is randomly listed in column 1, and its corresponding checkin time in column 2. Please help!!

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to map the location of the cell in the room map to a room number, then look up that room number in the "room times" table, then return the checkout time to the cell in the map.

Here's some sample code. This function is called from each of the cells in the room "map":

```
Function WhatTime(rngMap as Range, rngTime As Range)
    Application.Volatile

    Dim addr, v, rv

    addr = Application.Caller.Address(False, False)
    'find the room number...
    v = Application.VLookup(addr, rngMap, 2, False)

    If Not IsError(v) Then
        'got the room number: look up the time
        v = Application.VLookup(v, rngTimes, 2, False)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            rv = IIf(Len(v) > 0, Hour(v) - 12, "")
        Else
            rv = "" 'room not in time listing
        End If
    Else
        rv = "Room?" 'cell address not in cell<->room map
    End If

    WhatTime = rv

End Function
```

Setup example:
All cells in room map have formula `=WhatTIme($F$7:$G$11, $F$14,$G$18)`

[image]

Cells in the map are colored using Conditional Formatting.